# What's the function of present continuous in "Do we care.. are we caring about that"?

Tags: grammar

Here's a line from a 2005 film "Serenity":

— Conjure it might be the reason they're after her.

— You think maybe it poses some kind of threat to the Alliance?

— Do we care? ...Are we caring about that?

I'm baffled by the use of present continuous in this "are we caring about that". Does it serve a special literary function?

Comment: Note that much of the dialogue of *Firefly* and *Serenity* uses an invented faux-Western dialect with plenty of borrowing from archaic colloquialisms and invention of new ones. I don't think this is one, though; it's just casting a slight shade of meaning. I don't recall the tone, but I read it as shifting "Do we care [is that a thing we do, in general]" to "Is that a thing we're doing these days/at this time?".

Comment: Yes, it means something like "are we currently pursuing a policy that suggest we officially care about this?"